# Multithreaded socked server (chilkat, c)

Tags: chilkat

I want to setup socket server which receive incoming connections, and for each connections makes few operations (reveive bytes, check something, send response bytes). But every connection should work independly and if something goes wrong - dont block entire server.

I want to do it using chilkat socket and task libraries.

Where in source code could i put the receiving/processing/answering/code?
Just below CkTask_Run()?
I cant get the idea how forking is done, what is "old" process/thread doing, and where is new process going.
Is there any example to get an idea how it works, or could i get some low-level explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest solution is to write a multi-threaded application.  You have one thread for accepting new connections.  A new thread is started to run each accepted connection.  No async or tasks are necessary.  Each thread can operate with synchronous calls for reading/writing/accepting.